# Bound control keeping previous value

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm binding a `textbox` control to a data source using the `BindingSouce` component.

The databinding (in the designer) is as follows:

```
this.amountTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "Amount", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "C2"));
```

To test, I do the following:

1. Enter a value in the control
2. Tab further to other controls
3. Entered value stays in the control
4. Clear the value in the control (now it's empty, not 0)
5. Tab further to other controls
6. Control's value resets to the value entered in step 1

I've also tried `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` and setting 0 for the default null value. Bother have the same affect.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your BindingSource has to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (Consider [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)) and you Binding should hook into the `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`-Update Mode instead of `OnValidation`

Comment: @nozzleman I don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my dtasource because that's the job of the BindingSource.

Comment: Well then the `OnValidation`-UpdateMode might cause the issue (You passed "C2" ad the Format which might not validate on Empty Values). Have you tried defining `0` as null-value?

Comment: @nozzleman Yes. Same result.

Comment: what happens if at step 4, you just change the value instead of clearing it?

Comment: @nozzleman If the text is empty on `OnValidating` I set the text to 0. This works. However, this is a workaround for now and not a solution.

Comment: It's the normal behavior when there is a validation error/exception when assigning control value to data source value. What's the problem?